# How to use getActiveUniform in WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I was trying to debug an issue with my uniforms not working properly in WebGL and found getActiveUniform, that returns some information about the uniform (including name).
The signature is (according to specification):

```
WebGLActiveInfo? getActiveUniform(WebGLProgram? program, GLuint index);
```

I found to my surprise that it returned the same name for all uniforms at first, but then I looked at the signature again, and realized it takes an integer as second argument, and if I manually changed that to 0,1,2 etc it gave the uniforms. Unfortunately what you get from getUniformLocation is a opaque object.

Is this an oversight in the specification, or is there actually some way to call this function properly? (Because I can't find any).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *oversight*. WebGLUniformLocation is opaque on purpose. It's an opaque location id.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little unclear to me what you're asking, but I think it's “What is getUniformLocation useful for?”

It's useful for doing something with all uniforms if *the code doesn't already know what they are* (any kind of metaprogramming).

For example, I use it like this:

```
var uniforms = {};
for (var i = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.ACTIVE_UNIFORMS) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var name = gl.getActiveUniform(program, i).name;
  uniforms[name] = gl.getUniformLocation(program, name);
}
```

Then using the `uniforms` object I can write code like this, without any extra GL calls and without having to declare the uniform variable anywhere but the shader itself:

```
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uniforms.uPMatrix, false, pMatrix);
gl.uniform1f(uniforms.uFogDistance, fogDistance);
```

The same thing can be done with attribs using `getActiveAttrib` and `getAttribLocation` in the same way.

Comment: Not recommended for attributes because if you're debugging GLSL you may end up turning attributes off (either by commenting them out or them getting optimized out). In that case code like `gl.vertexAttribPointer(attribs.texcoord, ...)` will end up with `attrib.texcoord` being `undefined` which will coerced to `0` which will likely mess up your program. It works for uniforms because `undefined` gets coerced to `null` but the no-op for attribs is -1 not `undefined` or `0`. You could work around that though by wrapping all attribute functions to check for `undefined`.

Comment: you should also be aware that getActiveUniform can return info for things that aren't actually uniforms. example: https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/n6mzz6jv/